# Heroku not locating redis server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, redis

Still having trouble connecting to redis on Heroku. Everything works fine locally.

I installed the 'redis' gem and located the redistogo_url within the heroku website.  I also added the production env variable to heroku.

When I try to run a carrierwave backgrounder process which depends on redis and sidekiq, I keep getting the error below.

redis.rb

```
uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"])
REDIS = Redis.new(host: uri.host, port: uri.port, password: uri.password)
```

in a config file

```
if Rails.env.development?
  ENV['REDISTOGO_URL'] = 'redis:://@localhost:6379'
else
  ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"] = 'redis://redistogo:my_hash_key@greeneye.redistogo.com:9286/'
end
```

ERROR

`2015-03-21T04:44:47.560613+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/photos" host=www.luminoto.com request_id=92ad0e79-45c4-413d-8dc6-b3fdfe1754b8 fwd="98.222.43.13" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1396ms status=302 bytes=1609
2015-03-21T04:44:47.560695+00:00 app[web.1]: Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
2015-03-21T04:44:47.560721+00:00 app[web.1]: Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)`